# How to URL rewrite in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

My routes configuration only contains following route:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "frontend/home";
```

I would like to rewrite the default route

```
http://192.168.1.4/sncraft/frontend/home/about
```

to an url like this
    http://192.168.1.4/sncraft/about

The content of the controller is:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __Construct(){
        parent::__Construct();

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->load->model('frontend/front_model');
    }


    public function index(){
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url()."frontend/home";
        $this->viewForm();
    }   

    public function about(){
        $this->load->view('frontend/header');
        $this->load->view('frontend/about');
        $this->load->view('frontend/footer');
    }   
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

The key of the $route array is the actual url which leads to the function of the controller (without the base url).

Your route would look like this:

```
$route['about'] = "frontend/home/about";
```

I'm assume that your function inside the home-controller is called about().

You find more information here: [URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Have you added a function called about() in the frontend-controller? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I have a function about() in controller Home and don't find any error over there. I need only url rewriting as show you above.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the content of the controller file and the exact name of the file including the path? CodeIgniter is a bit tricky with file-naming conventions.

Comment: please check i have add some new

Comment: It looks like your controller is called 'Home'. Please take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: $route['about'] = "frontend/home/about";  DONE IT. THANKS DEAR

Comment: You're welcome :-) I missed the fact that it's possible place the controller in an additional folder - I corrected my answer.